# How to disable every click in page, only autofocus in input text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I only write text input and enter, disable every click or move cursor, just autofocus in text input?

```
<input autofocus placeholder="RR" name="RR" id="RR" type="text">
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
I found this method and worked :

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672762/disable-mouse-click-on-an-element-using-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').mousedown(function(e) {
            return false;
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

put `pointer-events : none;` in the css

put `cursor : not-allowed; /* or none to allow clicks*/` if you want to disable cursor.

[add `autofocus` to autofocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331022/focus-input-box-on-load):

```
<input autofocus placeholder="RR" name="RR" id="RR" type="text" autofocus>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help, but i want to disable every click or move cursor, just autofocus in text input.

Comment: can still click on the page, when i move cursor and click from autofocus text input to other area on page.